# MS Access overflow when I change queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Okay, I have built reports in MS Access 2007, and each report runs off of several (40+) queries. The queries are opening tables, subqueries, etc, and I don't think Access is closing them. I could be wrong, but for some reason I think this is causing the overflow.

But anyways, I am trying to figure out why it is happening all of a sudden, and what I can do to resolve it. I had the reports working fine when I just had a schema and some dummy data, but when the database was actually populated, the individuals who gave us the data created a few more look up tables, so now a typical query using 3 tables is now using 5.

Do you think this increase in look up tables (and therefore more objects being opened by Access) is the reason I am getting overflow errors, or could it be something else? Also, I don't know VBA, so are there any simple solutions (e.g. breaking up the reports, which would take a while) that would be worth pursuing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you really understand your "overflow" condition.  This code displays "Error 6 (Overflow)", without the quotes, in the Immediate Window.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    i = 32767
    i = i + 1

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.description _
        & ")"
    Debug.Print strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
```

The explanation for that error is that 32,767 is the maximum value a VBA Integer can accept.  So, attempting to add one would give 32,768 which is greater than an Integer can hold ... so overflow.

Other numeric data type also have limits.  For example, 2147483647 is the maximum value which can be stored as a VBA Long.

I might be totally off base here, but I would check whether your complex report includes sorting and grouping options where perhaps you produce totals.  And if so, whether the data you added pushes the values for any of those totals beyond the capacity of their respective data types.

If you're getting a different error message which includes the word "overflow", it might help to tell us the exact text of the error message.

Comment: Hey Hans, that was a great answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to fit my problem. Also, the error message simply says "overflow", nothing else. It's just a popup window without any details about the error.

Comment: Doesn't it also include an error number?  If it does, and the number is 6, you're probably dealing with an overflow similar to the one I described.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have a number. It's strange. Also, I do have fields greater than 32,767 (my highest is 6.1 million), but they are already set to long integers.

Comment: In that case I think your organization should bring in an experienced Access developer to sort this out.  I doubt we can resolve this for you on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyways. I'm accepting your answer because it is correct and someone will probably benefit from it.